# Import TypeScript file as string

Tags: typescript

I'm working on a code sample module and as of yet have not been able to figure out how to load a code sample from a file in typescript. Is there any way to import a TypeScript file as a string?

Comment: use `fs` library.

Comment: At build time or at run time?

Answer (score 0):

Use 'fs'.

```
import fs from 'fs'


fs.readFileSync('your-typescript.ts', 'utf-8')
```